# Problems overriding poll-bar.tpl.php using Omega subtheme

Tags: theming

I am trying to theme the Poll results. I decided to overwrite `poll-bar.tpl.php` by copying it inside my custom Omega theme directory. However, the changes are not visible after flushing cache nor after copying the template to templates directory.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you review the api documentation? http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!poll!poll.module/function/template_preprocess_poll_results/7

Comment: I do not want to override using template.php in my theme. I want to override the template file from poll module but theme is not picking it.